# Optimize fit of multiple segments to a curve

Tags: optimization, linear-approximation

I am developing an algorithm that approximates a curve using a series of linear* segments. The plot below is an example, with the blue being the original curve, and the red and yellow being an example of a two segment approximation. The x-axis is time and the y-axis is attenuation in dB. The ultimate goal is to use the least amount of segments while keeping the maximum error below a certain value. Clearly, since some portions of the curve are more linear than others, some segments can be longer than others.

[image: fitting segments to curve]

*The line segments are not actually linear, they are logarithmic. I am actually operating in log (dB) space, while the segments are linear in voltage.

My question is, how do I approach such an optimization problem? The method I am currently considering is to start at one end and select the longest segment possible, then move to the next segment and do the same. This will be good enough, in that it will keep me under my max error, but it may not be the best method. If it matters, I am working in Matlab.

Comment: Since you are operating in $log(dB)$ space, can you include that graph in your question?

Comment: @unseen_rider, the graph I've provided is in $log(dB)$ space. It's just that that the segments aren't actually linear.

Answer (score 2):

An approach would be this one:

1) Start with only one segment that connects start and end point of the curve.

2) find the point on the curve where the approximation error is maximum.

3) if the error is below the tolerance: go to step 5; else: continue

4) add one point exacly where the error is maximun, thus breaking the corrisponding segment into two new segments of lower error. go to step 2.

5) find the segment with the maximun height in y

6) if the height is below the limit: STOP; else: break the segment in half and go to step 5.

Comment: This is not a bad approach, though it won't always provide the minimum number of segments. What about the case where the minimum number is an odd number, so the middle segment would span the initial error maximum?

Comment: maybe now it's more clear, or maybe i didnt understand your objection to this algorithm.

Comment: Let's assume you have a circular arc as a curve. In this instance the best case will have all segments of equal length. By your algorithm, you could have 2, 4, or 8 line segments, but never 3, 5, or 6.

Comment: i see... to truly find the minimun number of segments you must try N points optimize them simultaneously so that the maximun error is the lowest, then see if it is below tolerance, and if not try N+1 points and reoptimize... You could do this using for example "Differential Evolution" (look on wikipedia), but this certainly is not very "low hardware specs" friendly

Answer (score 1):

Your problem reminds me of a similar one developed [here](http://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/5097/OR-300-94-26970351.pdf), in Chapter 4.

It is solved with a graph theory approach, more specifically with a shortest path algorithm that gives you the optimal set of knots.

It is pretty well detailed, take a look!

Comment: I'm afraid this is a bit above my head. Could you give a summary?